# z3 gmp support and type conversion

Tags: c++, z3, gmp

I have to convert an `mpq_t` into a `z3::expr`. The z3 README says: *"It is optionally possible to use GMP [...]."* How exactly would this look like? I couldn't find anything gmp related in the API documentation and the following does not work:

```
#include <z3++.h>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    z3::context c;

    mpq_t gmp_frac;
    mpq_init(gmp_frac);
    mpq_set_str(gmp_frac, "22/7", 10);

    z3::expr z3_frac = c.real_val(gmp_frac);
    std::cout << z3_frac << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It is possible to first convert the `mpq_t` into an `char` array (see below), but I am not very satisfied with that. Is there a more direct way?

```
#include <z3++.h>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    z3::context c;

    mpq_t gmp_frac;
    mpq_init(gmp_frac);
    mpq_set_str(gmp_frac, "22/7", 10);

    char char_frac[mpz_sizeinbase(mpq_numref(gmp_frac), 10)+mpz_sizeinbase(mpq_denref(gmp_frac), 10)+3];
    mpq_get_str(char_frac, 10, gmp_frac);

    z3::expr z3_frac = c.real_val(char_frac);
    std::cout << z3_frac << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's optionally possible to use GMP for the implementation of `mpz`'s, instead of Z3's own implementation. That comment does not mean that you can both at the same time, there will always be some conversion overhead.

Comment: Scanning https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classz3_1_1context.html#a0fce4849569272a6e1af194bee997675, It appears the only way to convert from GMP fraction to a Z3 real is indeed through `char[]`.

Comment: Thank you both. So did I understand this correct: using GMP's implementation of `mpz`s instead of Z3's own implementation would not help me since the API is still the same and I would still need "manual coversion"?

Comment: @Nicolai Yes; that's my understanding. You can also ask at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/discussions which might receive a more official answer.